# order items after JsonConvert.DeserializeObject using entity c# - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, json, api

I'm getting a result from an API then deserialize it and I want to sort the JSON but it doesn't work and gives me an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List...

my API :

```
 public async Task<Root_SDL> ValidateScenario(string SDL_text)
        {


            try
            {
                // Api Config
                var ApiPath = "something here";
                var SDL_version = "something here";
                // var SDL_text = something here;
                HttpClient httpClient_ = new HttpClient();
                var Keys = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                Keys.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("something here", SDL_version));
                Keys.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("something here", SDL_text));
                var ApiRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, ApiPath) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(Keys) };
                HttpResponseMessage ApiResponse = await httpClient_.SendAsync(ApiRequest);
                var responseString_ApiSDL = await ApiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                // ParserIssuesToJS = responseString_ApiSDL;
                
                var APIstatusCode = ApiResponse.StatusCode;

                // API Deserialize
              Root_SDL  SDL = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root_SDL>(responseString_ApiSDL);
                var test = (from c in SDL.issues select c)
                .Select(x => new
                
                {
                        x.description,
                        x.columnStart,
                        x.columnEnd,
                        x.lineStart,
                        x.lineEnd

                }
                )
                .OrderBy(x=>x.columnStart)
                .ToList()
                
                
                
                ;
              
                return test ; // here is the error (when I return SDL it works well but if I put 'test' that I miss a case or something)

            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

below is my json. I need from it the 'passed' value as well as the the issues array

```
{
    "Name": "something here",
    "passed": false,
    "issues": [
        {
            "description": "something here",
            "lineStart": 13,
            "lineEnd": 13,
            "columnStart": 4,
            "columnEnd": 10
        },
        {
            "description": "something here",
            "lineStart": 14,
            "lineEnd": 14,
            "columnStart": 30,
            "columnEnd": 31
        },
        {
            "description": "something here",
            "lineStart": 15,
            "lineEnd": 15,
            "columnStart": 29,
            "columnEnd": 30
        },
        {
            "description": "mismatched input '.' expecting ':'",
            "lineStart": 15,
            "lineEnd": 15,
            "columnStart": 36,
            "columnEnd": 37
        },
        {
            "description": "something here",
            "lineStart": 14,
            "lineEnd": 14,
            "columnStart": 28,
            "columnEnd": 30
        },
        {
            "description": "something here",
            "lineStart": 15,
            "lineEnd": 15,
            "columnStart": 27,
            "columnEnd": 29
        },
        {
            "description": "something here",
            "lineStart": 15,
            "lineEnd": 15,
            "columnStart": 34,
            "columnEnd": 36
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to sort it by **columnStart**

below is my Root_SDL class

```
public class Root_SDL
        {
            public string? fileName { get; set; }    
            public bool passed { get; set; }
            public string? parsingStartTime { get; set; }
            public string? parsingEndTime { get; set; }
            public List<Issue>? issues { get; set; }
            public List<string>? debug { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Could you show us your `Root_SDL` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of code which you return will not be a type of `Root_SDL`, if  you want to return that will not match with your return type from your method.

```
var test = (from c in SDL.issues select c)
            .Select(x => new
            
            {
                    x.description,
                    x.columnStart,
                    x.columnEnd,
                    x.lineStart,
                    x.lineEnd

            }).OrderBy(x=>x.columnStart).ToList()
```

From your question, you can only `order by` issues collection and  directly, that might only sort `issues` but reserve original property from `SDL`

```
Root_SDL SDL = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root_SDL>(responseString_ApiSDL);
SDL.issues = SDL.issues.OrderBy(x=> x.columnStart).ToList();
return SDL;
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5tdISZ)

Comment: yes but in this way i'll not be able to get the 'passed' element right?  @D-Shih

Comment: @FadiAkkad I just only `order by` you expect object `issues` the `passed` element still in `SDL` from original object

Comment: @FadiAkkad I add c# online fiddle which shows us that can keep `passed` element value

Comment: Thanks alot! it worked - I did not know that if I ordered the SDL.issues then I return the SDL, the SDL values will keep the sorting. @D-Shih